# Extract numbers from line not starting with comment symbol using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm try to replace all numbers not in the comment section. Here is a sample of the file to fix:

```
/* 2018-01-01 06:00:55 : realtime(0.002) --status(10)-- ++numretLines(0)++  --IP(192.168.1.5) PORT(22)-- queryNo(2)  comment[TO: Too much time]  TYPE[QUERY 4.2]  */
select count(*) from table where id1 = 41111 and id2 = 221144
GO
```

Basically, I would like to replace numbers in strings not beginning with `"/*"`.

I came up with the following regex: `/^(?!\/\*)(?:.+\K(\d+?))/gmU`

But I only manage to extract the first number of each line not starting with `"/*"`. How could I extend this to get all the numbers of those rows?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/iRNQOG/1

Comment: What technology are you using for your regex?

Comment: Looks like a good answer! Thanks! Would you like to put it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @AlfredoA. I'm using Perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) comment, I used `\/\*.*?\*\/(*SKIP)(*F)|-?\b\d+(\.\d+)?` to extract the numbers, including decimals and negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your regex engine (which you haven't told) supports `look behind` and `look ahead`, you can use this regex:

```
(?<!^\/\*.*)(?:(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s))+
```

The regex starts by using a `negative look behind`, looking for the `start of line`, followed by a `slash` and a `star`.

Then it creates a new `negative look behind` for a `White Space`, then any number of `digits`, followed by a `negative look ahead` for a `White Space`. This Group is `repeated any number of times`.

You need to set the `global` and `'multiline'` flag.

The regex skips numbers not surrounded by White Space (for instance `'id1'`)

Comment: I tried your regex in regex101.com, and it was complaining about * "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width". Appears to work, depending on the "flavor" I select. Is it something that is not supported by all languages?

Comment: Exactly, it's not supported by all flavors of regex. (You didn't write what flavor you use)